# What kind of vegetable plant might this be?

Tags: identification, vegetables

This plant began to grow in my vegetable garden in early March. I am in Bakersfield, California  It was about 4' tall.

[image]

Now, in April, it is almost 6' tall and now has yellow long blossoms.

[image: u]

Comment: This pic was the only one I had.. This is why I said, now has yellow long blossoms. Sorry for the mix up.

Comment: I took pics of the blossoms

Comment: Could you tell us where in the world this is growing? In the meantime, have a look in neighbouring gardens to see if it is growing anywhere else locally. Their owners may well be able to give you an identification: if so please post it as an answer to help other users.

Comment: I am in Bakersfield, California.. I've asked around before and nobody knows.

Comment: Are the leaves sticky and fuzzy?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a wild tobacco plant - Nicotiana Glauca...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotiana_glauca